# my raspberry pi rebooting and changing time suddenlly

Tags: raspbian

My rpi is rebooting after every 4-7 min and changing time suddenly.

[Here's the output of `tail -f /var/sys/syslog`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25627137/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This log is unreadable.. Please use a gist to make it easier.

Comment: @LuisDiaz I suggested an edit moving it to a pastebin, but it was rejected by the first reviewer

Comment: The syslog doesn't show anything and is trunkcated, could you add the rest of the syslog, and please don't post it here, use pastbin or similar.

Comment: And what kind of SD card are you using, ref @CharlieHorse answer.

Comment: Looks like you are using Solar Power, are you sure the supply is adequate?

Answer (score 1):

Either get a new power supply or format your SD card and download a fresh copy of your OS and rebuild it.  I seems that either your OS is corrupt or your power supply is inadequate.

Comment: What evidence is pointing to your answer? Some references would be nice.

Comment: Personal experience.  SD cards (particularly Classes 2, 4 and 6) are sometimes unreliable and inadequate power supply cause more problems in all computers than almost anything. With the data given, those are the two best possible answers.

Comment: Ok, so it is opinion and experience based. Perhaps you should change the answer to reflect it.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but problem still same.